# Flipping a QGraphicsItem on the X-axis "inplace" (left / right)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsitem

I have a `QGraphicsSvgItem` and would like to have two instances of it facing each other. I have recognized that using [`QGraphicsItem::setScale()`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setScale) method mentioning flipping and rotating in case of negative values, but thats not quite what I want.

I am probably only missing some clever use of the basic transformations, but somehow I had no success yet. With OpenGL I was able to set scaling for single axes, which did the trick.

Comment: post some code please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QTransform`:

```
item->setTransform(QTransform::fromScale(-1, 1));
```

Comment: You pushed me into the right direction. Contrary to the documentation, setScale() does take two parameters.

Comment: You mean `scale(qreal,qreal)`, but this is obsolete. You should use `QTransform` instead.